# React Native : Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision, Duplicate module name: react-animated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

I have 2 modules.

- react native-app
- react native storybook

[Download Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9h1knhf6kgv03i/demo-app.zip?dl=0)  *local.properties* put your android sdk path

Getting below error when I run **npm start**

```
Looking for JS files in
   /home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp 

Loading dependency graph...(node:9505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-animated
  Paths: /home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/storybook/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with /home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
    at setModule (/home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
    at workerReply (/home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:9505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9505) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:9505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-animated
  Paths: /home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/storybook/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with /home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
    at setModule (/home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
    at workerReply (/home/company/Desktop/projects/someapp/vendorapp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:9505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Not able to figure out tried lot of other stackoverflow links but none of them solved. Below are the details of **package.json** file

Let me know if any other details are needed.

**react-native storybook** `Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "storybook",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "storybook": "storybook start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.8.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/addons": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^4.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "16.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**react native app**

```
{
  "name": "vendorapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "storybook": "../storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: deleted **node-modules** in storybook and npm install in mobile app...   This worked for me @Daniel